# Sending Data from Raspberry Pi to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: raspbian

I have set up a temperature monitoring system using a Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian), MAX31855 Thermocouple to Digital Amplifier and a Thermocouple.

I have been able to get the hardware working and feeding data back to the device using SPI.

I am now attempting to send this data to Azure IoT hub, but I am continually coming to blocks along the way. Would anyone be able to give me any kind of guidance on the process of connection from Raspbian to Azure?

Any help appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Python, Microsoft have a sampler project here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-python-get-started. You'll need to create the Hub Account in Azure first, which will provide you with your connection details. Then you more or less follow their code. There is a REST API for most things on Azure so if your language of choice supports HTTP then you can make it do nearly anything.

Answer (score 0):

Below doc in detail instructs how to connect rasp with azure iot hub.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-node-get-started

The core of it is to instruct how to prepare the raspberry pi and create an azure iot-hub, and then make D2C and C2D messages happen following its sample codes. Per your description, you were merely blocked at the communication phase, so hope the send/receive message section in this instrumentation could unblock you.

Comment: While this might be an answer, it would be preferable if you would actually describe the procedure here, on the site, as to prevent link rot.